# Create windows service with current user account using sc.exe

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that creates a windows service which runs as the user who is currently running the batch file. In other word, if I, user_x runs the batch file, the created service will log on as me, user_x.

Since the user must be logged in to run the batch file, I am hoping there is a way to create the service without entering the user's password.

So far I've been using sc.exe to create a "Local system" windows service, and that works great. However I don't understand how to do the same for the current user. Any idea?

Comment: looking at help,  obj= <AccountName|ObjectName> (default = LocalSystem) - you already use LocalSystem - does it work if you use their username?

Comment: it works, but it requires a password, I think Harry's right and there is no way to not enter the password. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot create a service that runs as a user without knowing the user's password, even if you are already logged in as the user in question.  This is because the system has to save a copy of the user's password in the registry (using reversible encryption) in order to configure the service to run as that user.