# Can I run an unattended vb script on my server without being logged on?

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript that runs on my server and sends an email via telnet whenever a file is added to a certain directory.  The script runs continiously, however it will not execute the telnet commands if I am not logged on via RemoteDesktop.

Can anyone suggest a way to get this script to execute when I'm not logged on?

```
Option Explicit 
Dim fso, count, src, folder, file, ncount, cloner 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
src = "F:/serverfolders/public/camera" 
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(src) 
count = 0 
For Each file In folder.files 
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "mp4" Then 
  count = count + 1 
End If 
Next
ncount = count
WScript.Echo "Initial Count: " & count 

Do 

count = 0 
For Each file In folder.files 
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "mp4" Then 
  count = count + 1 
  End If
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "x" Then Exit DO
Next
if count > ncount then 
  Call Alarm()
  ncount = count
End If
WScript.Sleep 10000
Loop

Sub Alarm
cloner.run"cmd",1,false
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"telnet smtp.1and1.com 587"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.AppActivate "telnet smtp.1and1.com"
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"EHLO ****.com"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"auth login"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"password"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"password2"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"MAIL FROM: ****.com"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"RCPT TO: ****.com"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"DATA"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"Subject:Motion Alarm Detected"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"Motion Alarm Detected"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys"."
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 2000

cloner.SendKeys"quit"
cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

cloner.SendKeys("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 10000

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways:
1) [Create a new Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885976/create-windows-service-with-current-user-account-using-sc-exe?rq=1) using the [command line program](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) [SC.EXE](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx). The service would be configured to run your script, and it would need to use a specific account (new or existing). You would use the script.vbs as the executable file.

2) A [scheduled task](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).